# Material in rendered view differs between 3.1 and 3.0 when using mirror modifier

Tags: cycles-render-engine, mirror-modifier

I recently updated to Blender 3.1.2 and wanted to proceed working on a file I created in Blender 3.0.0
I use the mirror modifier for several objects. I defined one single empty as a mirror object which allows me to change the size of several objects by just changing the empty's location.

All objects render fine in 3.0.0. I do not have to apply the modifier, it just looks correct.
When opening the same file in 3.1.2 (after updating I started Blender with the prompt to import all existing settings from 3.0.0), the rendered view looks odd. I do not know what changed and every setting I checked between the versions is identical. Also applying the modifier does not help as the edges overlap and this somehow causes trouble in 3.1.2

I uploaded an example file. You can change the empty's x-location and the size of the board changes.

[image]

Any ideas if this is a settings problem or an actual bug?
Any hints are welcome. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why I didn't see this earlier, but when using the `bisect` (and in my case `flip`) option in the `mirror modifier`, everything works perfectly as overlapping geometry/faces are erased.
So no need for me to change the model, I just need to apply new modifier settings.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, finally I got it, it is a known issue:

> Many artifacts from rendering small, large and far away objects have been eliminated. There will always be object scales where numerical precision becomes a problem, but it's further out now.

> There can still be artifacts with rendering overlapping geometry, in some cases more severe than before. Such overlapping geometry should be removed, or have a small distance added in between.

https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/3.1/Cycles#Ray_Tracing_Precision

Comment: Thanks a lot for the link. Makes sense though it means some clean up work for me when rendering in 3.1.2